# How to write csv file with multiple columns using java

Tags: java, csv

I'm using java to create a csv File. I need the created csv file to have multiple columns.
So far, I'm using this code:

```
public static void writeCSV() {
    // Delimiter used in CSV file
    String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\\n";

    // CSV file header
    final Object[] FILE_HEADER = { "Empoyee Name","Empoyee Code", "In Time", "Out Time", "Duration", "Is Working Day" };

    String fileName = "./fileName.csv";
     FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    CSVPrinter csvFilePrinter = null;

    // Create the CSVFormat object with "\n" as a record delimiter
    CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);

    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);

        csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, csvFileFormat);

        csvFilePrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER); 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
            csvFilePrinter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the result of this code is this:
You can see in the first picture that when I opened the generated file with microsoft excel, you can see that all the header is written to the same column (column A) which is different from the ouput i want. The output that i really want is in the second picture ( which I created manually)

[image: when i open the generated file with microsoft excel, you can see that all the header is written to the same column (column A) which is different from the ouput i want]

[image: The output format that I REALLY WANT should look like this]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746499/csvprinter-datas-appears-not-separated-in-columns

Comment: There are many variants of CSV. You could either change the delimiter in excel (to `,`), or use `CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR).withDelimiter(';');` to set the delimter to `;` in your program.

Comment: Tip: [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) supports a Microsoft Excel specific variant of CSV.

Comment: @Marco13 thanks, your comment solved my problem